# Getting UnicodeDecodeError when installing gensim on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pip, gensim

I am trying to install `gensim` lib on Ubuntu using:

```
pip install --upgrade gensim
```

However, I got an error like this:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: gensim in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gensim-0.12.0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg
Collecting numpy>=1.3 (from gensim)
Downloading numpy-1.9.2.tar.gz (4.0MB)
100% |################################| 4.0MB 146kB/s 
Collecting scipy>=0.7.0 (from gensim)
Downloading scipy-0.15.1.tar.gz (11.4MB)
100% |################################| 11.4MB 55kB/s
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.2.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from gensim)
Collecting smart-open>=1.2.1 (from gensim)
Downloading smart_open-1.2.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
File "/tmp/pip-build-_nbem_oq/smart-open/setup.py", line 28, in <module>
    long_description = read('README.rst'),
  File "/tmp/pip-build-_nbem_oq/smart-open/setup.py", line 21, in read
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 4344: ordinal not in range(128)
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_nbem_oq/smart-open
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I can manually install the `gensim` lib by downloading and unzipping the tar.gz source for `gensim`, then run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: The downside with this is that now anyone installing that dependency will not have to know to install it separately rather than using pip.